# How can I specify a keyboard shortcut in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard, macros

How can I set the keyboard in Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) so I can map the function keys to write specified symbols?

I want to be able to write `\(` every time press <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a native way to do this, but there's an App called [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) that is capable of mapping keys to different ones.

1. Installing & launch it.
2. Open its preferences (from the menu bar icon > Preferences).
3. Go to the "Misc & Uninstall" tab and click on "Open private.xml", which will open a new Finder window in a folder with a file called private.xml.
4. Open private.xml with your favourite text editor and replace its content by this(*):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
       <item>
           <name>My F1 binding</name>
           <appendix>F1 = \(</append>
           <identifier>private.myf1</identifier>
           <autogen>
               --KeyToKey--
               KeyCode::F1, ModifierFlag::FN,
               KeyCode::BACKSLASH, KeyCode::KEY_9, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L
           </autogen>
       </item>
   </root>
   ```
5. Save the file.
6. Back in the Karabiner preferences, go to the tab "Change Key" and hit the button "ReloadXML".

(*) **Note 1**: This is for the US keyboard, as the resulting characters are keyboard-dependent.
For my own keyboard (Swiss German), for example, I'd have to replace the two `KeyCode` lines with this instead:

```
KeyCode::F1, ModifierFlag::FN,
KeyCode::KEY_7, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::KEY_8, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L
```

**Note 2:** If you have the keyboard setting *"Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys"* turned on (so that <kbd>FN</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> will decrease brightness), then you need to replace `ModifierFlag::FN` by `ModifierFlag::NONE`.